# PUSH уведомления Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, fcm

Как в приложении получать информацию о PUSH уведомлении если просто открыть приложение не нажимая(игнорируя) на само уведомление?

Answer (score 0):

Уведомления получает ваш класс основанный на сервисе FirebaseMessagingService в onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) - там же происходит создание уведомления.

Что-бы отправить какие-то данные в открытое Activity можно отправить из сервиса широковещательное (broadcast) сообщение а в нужной Activity это сообщение - ловить (прописывается  в манифесте приложения) см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464853/sending-data-from-service-to-activity

Comment: Да но если приложение в фоне то метод onMessageReceived не вызывается.

Comment: Видимо так, см. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive

Если приложение "убито" - уведомление приходит в "System tray"

Comment: А как достать сообщение из System tray?

Comment: Скорей всего никак. При выбре пользователем уведомления должно запустится ваше приложение.